# Exclude attributes from rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin, strong-parameters

I try to use rails_admin with strong_parameters and awesome_nested_set.

Probably because of awesome nested sets some attributes like `Lft` and `Rgt` show up in the **rails_admin** edit view of the respective model (category) and are editable. Once I change eg the name of the attribute and hit the save button I get the following error message:

```
Unauthorized assignment to lft: it's an internal field handled by acts_as_nested_set 
code, use move_to_* methods instead.
```

In an older version of my app I could just remove lft and rgt from the `attr_accessible` list (I don't want to manually edit them) but with **strong_parameters** this seems not to be possible.

Is there any war I can exclude certain attributes to be editable through **rails_admin**?

Answer (score 4):

I met the same error in the Rails 4 app (with `acts_nested_set` and `rails_admin`):

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError - Unauthorized assignment to lft: it's an internal field handled by acts_as_nested_set code, use move_to_* methods instead.:
  awesome_nested_set (3.0.0.rc.3) lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:127:in `lft='
  ...
```

This trouble appeared, because few fields was accessible in rails_admin. So, i just excluded them:

```
  rails_admin do
    navigation_icon 'icon-phone'

    edit do
      exclude_fields :id, :lft, :rgt, :children, :depth
    end
  end
```

And that was all.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to put **lft** and **rgt** attributes on **app/admin/model.rb** as permit_params like this:

```
permit_params :lft, :rgt
```

Think will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the solution was actually pretty easy. I just needed to add

```
attr_protected :lft, :rgt, :depth, as: :admin
```

to my category model.